# Error with targets shape while building a multi-class classification with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use an Artificial Neural Network for multi-class classification using Tensorflow with Keras.
I am buildung a model with the following shape:

```
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape`
```

```
(2000, 5, 5) (800, 5, 5) (2000, 4) (800, 4)
```

Labels are one-hot encoded.
Here is my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2],), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test)`
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: A target array with shape (2000, 4) was passed for an output of shape (None, 5, 4) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Where does the problem come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably reduce the dimension within your network. You have to go from 3d to 2d to match your goal. You can do this by using a global merge or smoothing layer. Try using `Flatten ()` before the output level or (`GlobalAveragePooling1D()` or  `GlobalMaxPooling1D()`)